# Naming previously undefined variable names from a dictionary value?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, variables, naming

I'm opening a lot of files at the beginning of my program and I'd like to avoid using 50+ separate lines of 'with open(....) as ....'. I'm looking for a way to map the file names to the variable names that the data will be stored in so that I can use a 'for' loop to open all files and save a lot of lines of code.

It seemed intuitive to me that a dictionary would suit this purpose well, but if I use the variable names as values, I get a 'name 'variableName' is not defined' error. I also tried storing the variable names as strings and while this doesn't produce an error message, it also doesn't seem to actually store the data (ie when I try to call the variable afterwards, it says the variable is not defined).

```
fileMapDict = {'file1': var1, 'file2': var2, 'file3': var3}

for file in fileMapDict:
    with open(file, 'r') as data:
        fileMapDict[file] = json.load(data)
```

As I say, this code produces a variable not defined error when I run the code, can anyone suggest a way to make this work?

Comment: Define the variables? Why do you expect to be able to use a variable that you haven't created without getting an error?

Comment: `fileMapDict["file"] = json.load(data)`

Comment: I'm guessing (and I have to guess because you didn't say) that it's complaining about `var1`. You have to define variables before you can use them. Just use `None` for the values in your dictionary, since you're going to replace them anyway.

Comment: "I also tried storing the variable names as strings and while this doesn't produce an error message, it also doesn't seem to actually store the data (ie when I try to call the variable afterwards, it says the variable is not defined)." Ah, I see what you are trying to do. Yeah, `dict` objects don't work like that. No objects really work like that. They do not store *variables*, they store *objects*. Variables are just ways that we reference objects in source code. Why do you want a bunch of variables anyway? Just *use the dict* which is *where the data is actually stored*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have a separate variable if you have the data in the dictionary.

```
files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']  # list of file names to open
fileMapDict = {}  # empty dictionary to store the data in

for file in files:  
    with open(file, 'r') as data:
        fileMapDict[file] = json.load(data)  # write data to dictionary with the file name as the key
```

Comment: Fixed my answer

Comment: You probably mean `fileMapDict[file]` instead of `fileMapDict['file']`

Comment: I modified it a bit for my purpose because I didn't want to have to enter the full file names every time I wanted to access the data (hence my attempt to use shorter variable names), but this framework worked for me. Thanks.